# Using tmap r package to plot a map in a shiny app, the tooltip remains the value in the left-most column of my data no matter what tooltop.vars I set

Tags: r, shiny, tmap

I am trying to set the tooltip that is shown when the user hovers over a feature in my map displayed in a shiny app. I am using tmap package to display the map in `view` (interactive) mode.
Below is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
  tm_shape(my_data()) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_fill(col = "population",
          style = "jenks", 
          palette = viridis(7),
          alpha = .6,
          tooltip.vars = c("sector"),
          popup.vars = c("Sector:"="sector", "Value:"="population"))
```

Yet, when I hover over a feature, the map still shows the tooltip of the value in my left-most column which is the ID of the feature. When I click, the popup is fine.

Is there something I am missing?

EDIT: I found out the `tooltip.vars` parameter actually doesn't exist. I should have used the `id` parameter for this instead.

Comment: Where is `tooltip.vars` documented in the `tmap` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `id=` to specify an identifier column to show on hover.

For example, using the data read in via `example(sf::st_read)`:

```
tm_shape(nc) + tm_borders() + tm_fill(col="PERIMETER", id="NAME", popup.vars=c("Area:"="AREA","B:"="BIR79"))
```

I'd still like to know where you got `tooltip.vars` from because I can't find it anywhere and it looks like something a large language model would come up with.

Comment: `looks like something a large language model would come up with` You got me here! Explicitly setting the `id` parameter works. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The real tip is to read the help pages, and not trust a machine that has read a million help pages and is guessing an answer for you! We learn!